# Switching Users Fully in Bash (GNOME/Keyring Issues)

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, gnome-keyring

I am confused about the difference between running a command as "user1" in a terminal and running a command as "sudo -Hiu user1 [command]".

If I run 
`/home/user1/script.sh`
, the script successfully calls a program that accesses GNOME/Keyring and the program gets the password without any issues.

However, if I run `sudo -Hiu user1 /home/user1/script.sh`, the program the script calls fails to access GNOME/Keyring successfully.

What is the difference between executing commands as user1 and running `sudo -Hiu user1 [command]` and how can I fully change users from e.g. root to user1 in bash?

Answer (score 0):

There is essentially no difference between running `sudo -Hiu user1 [command]` versus running `[command]` as `user1` (or even running `sudo [command]`), although there are some subtle differences (as mentioned in your question). Most of these are related to GNOME, which can be circumvented by using the `gksudo` command (or on newer systems, using `admin:///full/path/to/command arguments` or `pkexec [command] arguments`).

You can use `su user1` as root (or as any other user if you know the password) to run a shell as `user1`.